# How to get top 10 pages (according to views) of a site using GAPI (Google Analytics)?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to GAPI.. I want to find top 10 pages of site using GAPI for both mobile devices and desktop.. I coded up to this..

```
<?php
define('ga_email','xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com');
define('ga_password','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('ga_profile_id','xxxxxxxxxxx');

require 'gapi.class.php';

$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('browser','browserVersion'),array('pageviews','visits'));

//echo '<pre>';print_r($ga->getResults());exit;

?>
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Browser &amp; Browser Version</th>
     <th>Pageviews</th>
     <th>Visits</th>
   </tr>
<?php
  foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $result ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result->getVisits() ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  endforeach
?>
```

Comment: I think you forgot the question part? What's is the problem you are having with the code you posted? You do realize that GAPI hasn't been developed on since 2009.

Comment: gapi is deprecated, use the official google api for php instead. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client